# Laravel 5.3 multiple file uploads

Tags: php, file, laravel-5

How can I upload multiple files in `Laravel 5.3`.
If I try it with 1 image it works but multiple images are not uploaded.

This is my code:

```
if($request->hasFile('attachment')) {
    foreach($request->allFiles('attachments') as $file) {
        $file->store('users/' . $user->id . '/messages');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add Form::file('myfile[]', ['multiple' => 'multiple']);

Comment: I'm testing with postman. So yes I have done that.

Comment: @Jamie how do you save the paths now to DB??

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It works now like this:

```
$files = $request->file('attachment');

if($request->hasFile('attachment'))
{
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $file->store('users/' . $this->user->id . '/messages');
    }
}
```

I had to append `[]` after the value of the `name` attribute, so:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" multiple>
```

Comment: that what i mention on your question  Form::file('attachment[]', ['multiple' => 'multiple']);

Comment: But this is not working for me. only the last file is being uploaded

Comment: @Jamie `attachment[]` is not shown in your code? Do you mean it should be?

Comment: if you want to test via Postman, then you also have to append the key "file" to "file[]", then  multiple files are sent. Beware, because you can choose multiple files, even if [] are not appended to the key/name "file".

Answer (score 14):

This is Controller to upload multiple files in laravel:

```
    public function fileUpload(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasfile('filenames')) {
            foreach ($request->file('filenames') as $file) {
                $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move(public_path() . '/mytestfile/', $name);
                $data[] = $name;
            }
            return back()->with('Success!','Data Added!');
        }
    }
```

This view file in resources:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Multiple Image Upload</title>
    <script src="jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container lst">
    <h3 class="well">Test Muliple Image Upload</h3>

    <form method="post" action="{{url('image-upload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}

        <div class="input-group hdtuto control-group lst increment" >
            <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="myfrm form-control" multiple>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:10px">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".btn-success").click(function(){
            var lsthmtl = $(".clone").html();
            $(".increment").after(lsthmtl);
        });
        $("body").on("click",".btn-danger",function(){$(this).parents(".hdtuto control-group lst").remove();
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does this support a mp4/video and images in one post like Instagram?

Answer (score 4):

Solved it with this one a simplier approach. Just make sure that your input file type is like this `<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple>`

```
$i = 0;
foreach($request->file('images') as $file){
    $photo = new Photo;
    // name it differently by time and count
    $imageName = time() . $i . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    // move the file to desired folder
    $file->move('folderName/', $imageName);
    // assign the location of folder to the model
    $photo->image = 'folderName/' . $imageName;
    $photo->status = 1;
    $photo->save();
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this:

```
public function multiple_upload() {
    // getting all of the post data
    $files = Input::file('images');

    // Making counting of uploaded images
    $file_count = count($files);

    // start count how many uploaded
    $uploadcount = 0;

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $rules = array('file' => 'required');

        //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'

        $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);

        if($validator->passes()){
             $destinationPath = 'uploads';
             $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
             $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
             $uploadcount ++;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not with the new features off Laravel 5.3 right?

Answer (score 1):

**Controller.Php** / **Laravel 5.7.28**

```
$files = $request->file('product_image_id');
if($request->hasFile('product_image_id')){
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $name = time(). $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images',$name);
        $productImage = ProductImage::create(['image'=>$name]);
        $input ['product_image_id'] = $productImage->id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still working with blade you can use this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'upload', 'files'=>true)); }}
{{ Form::file('gallery[]', array('multiple'=>true,'accept'=>'image/*'));  }}
{{ Form::submit();  }}
{{ Form::close();  }}
```

And in your Controller :

```
files = $request->file('gallery');

if($request->hasFile('gallery'))
{
    foreach ($files as $file) {
       // $file->store('users/' . $this->user->id . '/messages');
        //dump($file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how my blade looks like:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="gallery-image" class="col-sm-3 text-left control-label col-form-label">Photo</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    {{-- <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple> --}}
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control form-control-file"
                                     id="gallery-image" value="{{ old('gallery-image') }}" required name="gallery-image[]" multiple/>
                                     <span class="below-image-upload-msg">Advised image dimensions: 1920 x 450 pixels. File size should be less than 2Mb per image.</span>
                                </div>
                                @error('image')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
```

And this is how the store function in the controller looks like:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), array(
        'gallery-id'    => 'required|integer|min:0',
        'gallery-image' => 'required|image|nullable|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
    ));
    $fileNameToStore="no-image.jpg";

    if(request('gallery-image'))
    {
        $iCount=0;
        foreach($request->file('gallery-image') as $thisImage){
            $fileNameWithExtension = $thisImage->getClientOriginalName();
            $memberName = Auth::user()->MemberProfile->member_tourist_office_name;
            

            $extension=$thisImage->getClientOriginalExtension();
            
            $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().$iCount.'.'.$extension;

            $path= $thisImage->storeAs('public/images/members/gallery-images',$fileNameToStore);


            $isEnabled                                   = "0";   
            $galleryImage                                = new GalleryImage();
            $galleryImage->gallery_id                    = request('gallery-id');
            $galleryImage->gallery_image_caption         = " "; 
            $galleryImage->gallery_image                 = $fileNameToStore;
            $galleryImage->isEnabled                     = $isEnabled;

            $galleryImage->save();
            $iCount++;
        }
        return redirect('/galleryimage/create')->with('success', 'Image(s) successfully added to gallery!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public function MultiImage(Request $request)
{
    $postimage=new Photo;

   if($request->hasfile("file")){
        foreach($request->file("file") as $img) {
            $filename = $img->getClientOriginalName();
            Image::make($img)->resize(200, 200)->save('banner/uploads/photo/'.$filename);
            $uploadPath = 'banner/uploads/photo/'.$filename;
            $data[]=$filename;
        }
        $postimage->code = time();
        $postimage->name = $filename;
        $postimage->private_state = $request->input('private_state');
        $postimage->description = $request->input('description');
        $postimage->titre = $request->input('titre');
        $postimage->mute = $request->input('mute');
        $postimage->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
        $postimage->save();
    }        
    return redirect()->route('timeline-photos');
}
```

je veux enregistrer plusieurs images dans la base de donnees avec laravel. voici mon code et ca n'enregistre qu'une seule image.
cordialement,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).