# Multiple file is not uploading in laravel 5

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to upload multiple files. But it seems that only the last file is passing through the post request. What is the problem?

> Here is my view file

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="/storeProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {!! csrf_field() !!}
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Upload image</label>
          <input type="file" id="files" name="file[]" multiple>
          <output id="list"></output>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

And controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
        echo $count;
```

}
The count always become 1 no matter howmuch file i upload

Comment: try from this topic.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846148/laravel-5-3-multiple-file-uploads?rq=1