# how to view images that stored as array in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, database, image, laravel

user upload multiple image and it stored in array form. how to display those images in laravel blade file?
when i tried i got this error.

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\Users\user\laravel2\newfyp\resources\views\postqs\show.blade.php)
```

**show blade :**

```
   <img src="/image/{{ $postqs['image'] }}" 
    style="width:150px; height:150px;"> </td>
```

**model:**

```
  protected $casts = [
    'image'=>'array', ];

 protected $fillable = ['image'];
```

**create blade**

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >image test:
             </label>
                    <form action="upload" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" multiple><br />

                </form>
                <div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 multiple file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846148/laravel-5-3-multiple-file-uploads)

Comment: could you show the dummped array code ? I mean dump the array and show the results here

Comment: `$postqs['image']` is an array not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
@foreach($postqs['image'] as $imagePath)
    <img src="/image/{{ $imagePath }}" 
        style="width:150px; height:150px;"> 
@endforeach
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $fillable = [''image'];
```

Is that a typo with the double quote?

If the images are in an array simply loop over the array and create an img for each.

Have you tried something like the following in your view file:

```
@foreach ($postqs['image'] as $image)
    <img src="asset({{ $image }})" />
@endforeach
```

Comment: How are you looping the array? If the path is correct for each image within the array it should resolve no problem. I use the `asset` helper to link to public resources also like: `<img src={{ asset('/images/someimage.png') }} />`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should correct this line:

```
protected $fillable = [''image']; // ['image'] and not [''image']
```

`htmlspecialchars():` I always get  this error when the variable is null.

A simple solution would be wrap your html with:

```
@if($yourVar)
@endif
```

You can also dump your variable to show how the structure is.

Good luck.