# upload multi file to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, upload

hi i have laravel project 
and this is my html file

```
<tr>
    <td>{{trans('language.files')}} </td>
    <td colspan='2'><input type='file' multiple  name='files[]'  class='form-control' required /></td>
</tr>
```

as you can see its file as array of files 
and this is the controller code

```
if($request->files != null)
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach($request->files as $key=>  $file)
    {
        if(!empty($image))
        {

            $user_id = $request->user_id;
            if(!file_exists(storage_path()."/app/public/$user_id"))
                File::makeDirectory(storage_path()."/app/public/$user_id");     
            // code to upload file $file[$i] in             }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

i tried to upload file using `move` method but i gat uploaded file as temp extension inside storage folder 
thanks a lot

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53701116/3226121) on how to upload file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 multiple file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846148/laravel-5-3-multiple-file-uploads)