# Laravel, "getimagesize(asda.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, laravel

Guys I am trying to upload multiple images in laravel.

Blade:

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
    <input type="file" class="form-control m-input" name="event_images[]" multiple required >

</div>
```

Controller:

```
$images =  $request->event_images;

if (is_array($images) || is_object($images)) {

    foreach ($images as $file) {

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $final_filename = $file->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;
        Storage::disk('public')->put($final_filename, File::get($file));

        $thumb_img_250 = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(250, $new_height_250);
        $thumb_img_250->save(storage_path('app/public/event_images/image_250') . '/' . $final_filename, 80);

        $thumbs_real = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
        $thumbs_real->save(storage_path('app/public/event_images/real_image') . '/' . $final_filename, 80);


        $image = new EventImages();
        $image->image = $file->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;
        $image->save();

    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', sprintf('Images were sucessfully added'));

}
```

But what is get is this error:

> "getimagesize(asda.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory"

This has never happend to me. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your $file is instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile.
Try:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file->path());
```

Comment: It says call to a member function path() on string

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846148/laravel-5-3-multiple-file-uploads
Debug your variable types in each step with var_dump().

Comment: Make sure that form's enctype=multipart/form-data