# File upload using foreach in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Been working on this problem for 2 days and still cannot figure it out.  I am trying to upload multiple files into storage in my Laravel project.  I know my code works up to the foreach as I tested this with dd.

**My controller:**

```php
$files = $request->file('current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1');
$folder = public_path(). "\storage\\$id";

if (!File::exists($folder)) {
    File::makeDirectory($folder, 0775, true, true);
}

if (!empty($files)) {
    foreach($files as $file) {
        Storage::disk(['driver' => 'local', 'root' => $folder])->put($file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.3 multiple file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846148/laravel-5-3-multiple-file-uploads)

Comment: No, but thank you.  I did see that and think that is a totally different way of approaching the issue which I cannot understand.

Comment: what is the problem??

Comment: I have a form that has multiple files to upload from the form (i.e. Current Plan file, Prior Plan file, etc).  When the user uploads some or all of those files, I want my Controller to create a folder with the $id if it doesn't exist.  This part of my code works.  After, it should put all those files in that folder.  This part does not work.

Comment: I am not getting any error messages, but the file never gets saved

Comment: Storage take care of creating the folder when it doesn't exists. I don't see the problem of using `$file->store($id);` as `$id` the name of the directory.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files?

Importantly, your file input needs to be an array if you would like multiple files, e.g. ```<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>```

Comment: Also, you're trying to create a folder in the **public** storage symlink `public_path(). "\storage\\$id";`  while storing the file in the **local** storage `Storage::disk(['driver' => 'local', 'root' => $folder])` What do you want to do with these files?

Comment: His file inputs don't HAVE to be an array, they just need to be if he wants to use $request->allFiles('file_list') or whatever

Comment: Thanks.  The folder is now being created and the file is showing in the directory, but now I get this message in my browser after I upload.

file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\HealthHub\storage\app\3/files): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that you are trying to store the files directly in `public` folder, but why not use the `Storage` API of Laravel and use the public disk? You can do something like this to upload the files to the public directory:

```php
$id = 123;
$files = $request->file();
$folder = $id;
if (count($files) > 0) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $file->store($folder, ['disk' => 'public']);
    }
}
```

And be sure that you have linked the storage path to public:

```sh
php artisan storage:link
```

Focus on `$files = $request->file();` line. When you don't pass an argument to `file()` method, all uploaded file instances are returned. Now when you will loop over the `$files` array, you will get access to individual uploaded files.

And then you can store the file using your logic, i.e. you can use the original name or whatever else. Even you can use the `Storage` facade to process the file instance.

i.e. if you want to store the files with their original names, I find this a cleaner way rather than what you are doing:

```php
$id = 123;
$files = $request->file();
$folder = $id;
if (count($files) > 0) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs(
            $folder,
            $file,
            $file->getClientOriginalName()
        );
    }
}
```

And as suggested by @cbaconnier, you can use `allFiles()` method too that's more descriptive:

```php
$files = $request->allFiles();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You still have the root issue here of trying to loop over a single UploadedFile instance.

Comment: @ZacharyCraig The `_1` is very tendentious but we should see the form before affirming that `current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1` is not an array of files.

Comment: @ZacharyCraig Please check updated answer. `$request->file()` returns the array of all uploaded files even if they have different field names.

Comment: Side-note: You can also use `->allFiles()` which is less confusing

Comment: @cbaconnier Thanks, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Wow, beautiful.  Thanks Rehmat.  That finally works.  I had been trying to find that solution for two days.  Thanks for explaining so clearly.

Comment: @Alexander Glad to know that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to iterate over files, and file is just a reference to request->file(), which is a SINGLE `UploadedFile` object.

As indicated by your comment, you have multiple file inputs with different name attributes, so you can't easily loop over them with one statement, eg: if you had multiple files all uploaded as "attachments[]" as the input name attribute, you could get them all with `$request->allFiles('attachments')`, however, if you want to keep the input names as they are, this should be close to what you want.

```
public function foo(Request $request, $id){
    $folder = public_path(). "\storage\\$id";

    if (!File::exists($folder)) {
        File::makeDirectory($folder, 0775, true, true);
    }

    $files = array();
    $files[] = $request->file('current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1');
    $files[] = $request->file('prior_plan_year_claims_data_file_1');
    $files[] = $request->file('etc_file_whatever');

    foreach($files as $file) {
        Storage::disk(['driver' => 'local', 'root' => $folder])->put($file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
    }
}
```

Side note, i'm not sure what you're doing with File and public_path, but if your goal is just to put something in your app storage, something like this should work fine

```
public function foo(Request $request, $id){
    if(!\Storage::exists($id)){
        \Storage::makeDirectory($id);
    }

    $files = array();
    $files[] = $request->file('current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1');
    $files[] = $request->file('prior_plan_year_claims_data_file_1');
    $files[] = $request->file('etc_file_whatever');

    foreach($files as $file) {
        \Storage::put("$id/" . $file->getClientOriginalFileName(), $file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this second version and it does create the folder properly, but I get an error message I cannot seem to fix:  

Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

When I dd($file) within the foreach, it shows it has the file.

Comment: You might have to wrap the $request->file calls within a check to make sure those files exist in the request first

Comment: I was able to create the proper folder within public\storage using the $id and that did save the file.  But, now in my view I get a tmp file name instead of the original file name and cannot figure out how I could display the original file name in a dynamic fashion.  Here is what I currently have in my view:

         <a class='col-6' href="/download/{{ $plansubmission->id }}/{{$plansubmission->current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1 }}">{{ $plansubmission->current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1 }}</a>