# laravel tries to store multiple images but only store of them multiple times

Tags: laravel

I've sending multiple distinct (already checked them) images to server and in laravel controller I have this:

```
//...

if ($request->has('images')) {
    $images = [];
    foreach ($request->file('images') as $image){
        $img = new \App\Image;
        $name = Str::slug($validated['name']).'_'.time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $folder = '/uploads/images/authors/';
        $image->storeAs($folder, $name, 'public');
        $img->url = $folder.$name;
        array_push($images,$img);
    }

    $author->images()->saveMany($images);
}

//...
```

then I look into the destination path in storage and found one of the images repeated multiple time with different names.

so what's the problem?

Comment: I think if you change this line, It will work too `$img = $folder.$name;`

Comment: @sta but `$img` is their model instance, `saveMany` takes model instances

Comment: i am kinda surpised you don't have less images than expected as `time()` could be returning the same result depending on how fast that loop iterates

Comment: @lagbox stored images all have different names but contents are the same. so I don't think time() is the issue.

Comment: What does your file upload HTML input look like?  There are plenty of examples here on SO, have you checked them?  Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846148/laravel-5-3-multiple-file-uploads

Comment: might want to check what `$request->allFiles()` looks like, just in case

Comment: @Reundo $validated['name'] won't change throughout each iteration. I'm guessing each file is overwriting the last one. you can use the `logger()` helper and log the name each time you iterate. You should see a few lines in the log at different times with the same name.

Comment: @lagbox nothing is changed. only `$request->allFiles()` returns array of arrays.

Comment: i wasn't saying anything would change, it was just to make sure the structure looks as you expect, it was for you to see what it "looks like, just in case"

Comment: @yes I know :) tbw. adding `Str::random()` to `$name` solve the issue but I don't know why. if `time()` was the issue then wht file names were different

Comment: did you have a clear directory every time this end point was hit ... or were you keeping the previous runs files in it every time?

Comment: @lagbox no I didn't clear the directory. why?

Comment: potentially because the filename could have been the same for every file in the loop, which would mean there would only be 1 file (the last one) ... and every time you ran this there would be 1 more file added (the last one in the loop) and if you keep using the same exact data every time you ran this, all the files would be the same content in the end because the filename wasn't changing in the loop (if this took less than a second to do) as `time()` is based on seconds

Comment: @lagbox . yeah it is make sense. I guess that was the problem because after every attempt only one or two were added to directory but because i didn't clear the directory I didn't notice it back then. thanks again.

Comment: hehe np, i tried to cut this short an hour ago :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your filename destination unique.

```
if ($request->has('images')) {
    $images = [];
    foreach ($request->file('images') as $image){
        $img = new \App\Image;
        $name = Str::random(8).'_'.Str::slug($image->getClientOriginalName()).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        // Debug:
        logger('Received a file named '.$image->getClientOriginalName().' storing as '.$name);

        $folder = '/uploads/images/authors/';
        $image->storeAs($folder, $name, 'public');
        $img->url = $folder.$name;
        $images[] = $img;
    }

    $author->images()->saveMany($images);
}
```

Comment: I add a `Str::random()` to `$name` and code works. thanks but I don't know why.

Comment: @Reundo Your $validated['name'] is the same each time. You can pass the filename directly, laravel will make sure it's a valid and acceptable file name

Comment: `$validated['name']` wasn't the issue. and I know laravel does that but I edit some attributes and want the original request too.