# update multiple images in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have uploaded multiple image successfully. but I cant update them. How to update multiple images in laravel? my store multiple images from controller is-

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $service = new Service;
    $service->menuName = $request->menuName;
    $service->subTitle = $request->subTitle;
    $service->description = $request->description;
    $service->shortDescription = $request->shortDescription;

    $images=array();
    if($files=$request->file('file')){
        $i=0;
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileNameExtract=explode('.',$name);
            $fileName=$fileNameExtract[0];
            $fileName.=time();
            $fileName.=$i;
            $fileName.='.';
            $fileName.=$fileNameExtract[1];

            $file->move('backend/images/user/',$fileName);
            $images[]=$fileName;
            $i++;
        }
        $service['photos'] = implode("|",$images);

        $service->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: I recommend changing the `photos` field to `JSON` in your database, and using Laravel abilities to hash names and save files in storage like this:


`$photo = $request->file('file')->move('backend/images/user/', $request->file('file')->hashName());`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.3 multiple file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846148/laravel-5-3-multiple-file-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

Your image filenames appear to be in an array in the model.

To add a new image, upload and save the image as you have here, and then add the image filename to the end of the array, then save the model.

To delete an image, show each of the images inside a form, with some way of selecting an image with a checkbox for instance. The value of the checkbox should be the filename. When a selected checkbox is posted to the server, delete the file, remove its filename from the array and resave the model.

Really, I would recommend the images had their own table with one image per row and the a belongs to relationship with the original model.